# What are the officially supported browsers and platforms for Live Apps?

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm writing a Live App and was wondering if there was an official list of platforms, browsers, browser versions (etc.) that I should test my Live App on, to make sure that all Quip users have a great experience.

Currently my test plan includes:

- the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Edge for both Mac and Windows
- the latest versions of Chrome and Safari for Android and iOS respectively

Answer (score 1):

This is a great testing plan and an awesome question. Just a few thoughts to make this even better

- Instead of testing on mobile web, test on our Android and iOS Quip apps.
- In addition to the browsers, I would recommend testing on our Mac and PC desktop apps, available at quip.com/download.